# why my django groundwork doesn't work

Tags: django

I install django-groundwork by pip and set add 'groundwork' to the my django app but it seems doesn't work,I don't know why?When I use command 'python manage.py help' to check which command could be used ,there is no 'ground' but the module dose exist.Please give me some help

Comment: the documentation tell to add 'groundwork' not 'ground'

Comment: sorry my typing mistake,I add 'groundwork' actually

Comment: Is it added to your installed apps setting in your settings.py?

Comment: yes I do.The module seems could be found but not work

Answer (score 0):

The groundwork pagkage doesn't provide any management commands. It only provides some templates and template tags. That's why you're not seeing anything when calling manage.py (or django-admin.py'

The docs say it clearly, but you can check out the code... there's simply no management/commands directory inside the installed package.

> Groundwork is a small set of template tags and filters that simplifies
>   working with Zurb Foundation

To truly say that the application "doesn't work", you'd have to use the template tags it provides.

Do this in a template
`{% load groundwork_tags %}`

Then do this
`{% groundwork_icon 'info' '5em' 'text-centered' %}`

If  that breaks your template, it means the app isn't properly installed, is broken, or otherwise there's something else wrong.

Read about django management commands a little, it will all be clear (make sure to read about the version of django that you have installed.. the link will always point to the development version so things might be different there):
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/